# redirect page without changing url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote code on my index page

`window.location.replace(www.mysite.com/index2.html);`

it redirects, but it also change the url which is obvious.

For e.g. when I run `www.mysite.com/index.html`

It should run `www.mysite.com/index2.html` page and browser address should display `www.mysite.com/index.html`.

I want to do this in jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without spoofing the browser's history. You can find an example here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#section_4

Otherwise, you can use a frame to display `index2.html` in `index.html`

Note that the `history.pushState()` is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: I know this can be done by server.transfer in classic asp pages. I am curisos to do this in jquery.